# Rails generate commands not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a migration using the rails generator, but when I run `rails g migration create_meetups_table`I get the following output:

```
Could not find slop-3.4.7 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I installed the gem manually and then ran bundle install again and got this output:

```
Using i18n 0.6.9
Using json 1.8.1
Using minitest 5.3.4
Using thread_safe 0.3.4
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using rake 10.3.2
Using rack 1.5.2
Using polyglot 0.3.5
Using mime-types 1.25.1
Using arel 5.0.1.20140414130214
Using bcrypt 3.1.7
Using coderay 1.1.0
Using coffee-script-source 1.7.0
Using execjs 2.2.0
Using thor 0.19.1
Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
Using geocoder 1.2.2
Using hike 1.2.3
Using multi_json 1.10.1
Using method_source 0.8.2
Using pg 0.17.1
Using slop 3.4.7
Using bundler 1.6.2
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using sass 3.2.19
Using spring 1.1.3
Using rdoc 4.1.1
Using tzinfo 1.2.1
Using rack-test 0.6.2
Using warden 1.2.3
Using treetop 1.4.15
Using coffee-script 2.2.0
Using uglifier 2.5.1
Using pry 0.9.12.4
Using sprockets 2.11.0
Using sdoc 0.4.0
Using activesupport 4.1.1
Using mail 2.5.4
Using actionview 4.1.1
Using activemodel 4.1.1
Using jbuilder 2.1.0
Using actionpack 4.1.1
Using activerecord 4.1.1
Using actionmailer 4.1.1
Using railties 4.1.1
Using sprockets-rails 2.1.3
Using coffee-rails 4.0.1
Using devise 3.2.4
Using jquery-rails 3.1.0
Using rails 4.1.1
Using sass-rails 4.0.3
Using rMeetup 1.0.1 from git://github.com/tannermares/rmeetup.git (at master)
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

I can clearly see that the gem is being bundled. I can run other commands for starting the app and the console but can't run the generate migrations. Any thoughts on how to fix this? I've tried the deleting the install of ruby and reinstalling but that did not help.

Comment: From your project root directory fire `bundle install`.. then try.. It will work

Comment: @ArupRakshit I've tried that with no luck.

Comment: Is it any different if you try `bundle exec rails...`? Are you using anything like `rvm` or `rbenv`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think [Spring](https://github.com/rails/spring) is misbehaving, and not re-requiring gems correctly.

Check spring's status with `bin/spring status`.  If it's running, try stopping it with `bin/spring stop`.  If it's not, check to see if there are any orphan Spring processes that might be screwing things up:

`ps aux | grep spring`.

I'm not entirely sure *why* Spring is acting like this, but killing it off fixed the issue for me.  I was unable to replicate again to investigate further.

Comment: spring stop and spring server helped

Answer (score 2):

You may well be picking up the wrong version of Rails. Prefixing your rails commands with bundle exec should sort things out for you so

```
rails g migration create_meetups_table
```

becomes

```
bundle exec rails g migration create_meetups_table
```

Also add the gem to your Gemfile.rb and run bundle install this will ensure that bundler is knows about the right gems when you use it to execute rails commands.

Using RVM or RBENV might be a better long term solution for you.

https://rvm.io/

https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv